# How to start my own script at the END of boot

Tags: boot, sound, python, systemd

I am trying to run my own python script at startup. Or more specifically at the END of the boot sequence
The python code does

a) writes to the I2C LCD screen

b) announces via sound that its 'Ready'
When tested in a normal session this all works.

I tried, and suceeded, in creating a systemd service for this. The issue is that it runs too early - the screen is written to but the sound does not play.
My guess is this would need an 'After' directive in the service setup but I have no idea what to schedule it 'After'
Asking systemd for info yields a list of either 258 or 360 things its looking after - no help really.
I tried adding After=sound.target but that didn't help
So, is there a generic 'when-you-have-finished-all-your-stuff' thing that I could use to trigger my 'user' needs after all the 'system' needs ?

```
[Unit]
After=sound.target
Description=Execute this on boot

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/jc/jcCode/at_start_pyscript.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Thanks
JC
```

Comment: Try starting your script from cron using `@reboot` time specification.

Comment: Try changing `After=sound.target` to `After=graphical.target` or `After=default.target`. Sound doesn't seem to have any prerequisites, but the other two do (and are the same, actually).

Comment: Doug - I think I have stumbled onto a more significant issue which has to be solved before I try your suggestions.  The audio output device is being reset to 'Analog Output' on every boot. So it might be playing the sound to the big bit-bucket in the sky.  BTW how did you determine the prerequisites ? Will it divulge a tree list of everything ?

Comment: I just looked around and guessed. Not very engineering like.

Comment: @raj I tried the 'reboot' thing and it worked first time.  Much easier than all the other stuffing around. Thanks

Comment: @jc508 so I'm putting it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try starting your script from cron using `@reboot` time specification. For example create a file `/etc/cron.d/myscript` with the following contents:

```
@reboot root /usr/bin/python3 /home/jc/jcCode/at_start_pyscript.py
```